# плагин WordPress Automatic

Tags: wordpress, wp-plugin

Есть новостной сайт, с вкладками HOT NEWS,Politics,Economy и т.д. Как настроить плагин чтобы он выкладывал посты на разные страницы сайта?

Comment: Поищите в [документации](https://s3.amazonaws.com/valvepress/documentation/index.html)